# Cryptic error when attempting to create PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, compiler-errors, sqlplus

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SUPPLIER (Tradename IN DRUG.Tradename%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2 
    IS 
        returnString VARCHAR2(32767);
    BEGIN

        returnString := lpad('*',32767,'*');
        SELECT Formula,Pharname INTO returnString FROM DRUG 
        WHERE Tradename=Tradename;


        RETURN returnString;

    END;
    /
```

When i attempt to create this function, it says this :

```
Warning : Function created with compilation errors.
```

When I execute "show err", I get this :

```
LINE/COL ERROR                                                                  
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------      
7/2      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored                                          
7/44     PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

ORA-00947 "not enough values"

is being raised on line 7:

```
SELECT Formula,Pharname INTO returnString
```

You are selecting two columns, but you only provide one variable to put them in.

You can either add a second variable, or use some kind of expression to concatenate the values, e.g.:

```
SELECT Formula,Pharname INTO returnFormula,returnPharname
```

or

```
SELECT Formula || Pharname INTO returnString
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! My compilation error is now resolved. But  i'm now getting "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" when i attempt to call the function.

Comment: That means there is more than one record that matches your query predicate.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should read `WHERE SUPPLIER.Tradename = DRUG.Tradename`.